# Elegant way to match protobuf message type in Rust

Tags: enums, rust

I am working on a protobuf Rust project. The type is required to be known in order to parse a message, so the ID (a `u32`) is sent and matched to a enum (`MessageType`). Depending on the type, another match is required on that enum value to determine the actual type. A simplified version looks like:

```
use protobuf::core::parse_from_bytes;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug)]
pub enum MessageType {
    Neither = 0,
    TypeA   = 1,
    TypeB   = 2
}

impl From<u32> for MessageType {
    fn from(id: u32) -> Self {
        match id {
            1 => MessageType::TypeA,
            2 => MessageType::TypeB
            _ => MessageType::Neither
        }
    }
}

fn decode_message(&mut self, m_type: Option<MessageType>) -> Result<..., ....> {
     // some code before...

     let m = match m_type {
        &Option::Some(MessageType::TypeA) => parse_from_bytes::<TypeA>(&mut (self.body.as_mut() as &mut [u8]))?,
        &Option::Some(MessageType::TypeB) => parse_from_bytes::<TypeB>(&mut (self.body.as_mut() as &mut [u8]))?,
        _ => panic!("unknown type")
    };

    // do something with m...
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to bind the generic message type to the enum to eliminate the match required in `decode_message`?

Comment: Why split it up at all? That is, why not just have `fn decode_message(id: u32, data: ...) -> Result<..., ...> { match id { 1 => parse::<TypeA>(...), ... } }`